# prevent error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object without global?

Tags: php, connection

I am trying to implement simple calls to the database using PHP.

I have received the following error `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` **YES** there are many questions on this subject, but the answers to me aren't well explained, especially as I don't want to create a new connection all of the time.

When registering a user I have **register.php** within this there are the standard $_GET for data etc, before finally calling **insertUser($param,$param,$param,$param)** within the **db_functions.php**

```
public function insertUser($name, $email, $gender, $dob, $password){

        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encryptedPassword = $hash["encrypted"];
        $salt = $hash["salt"];

        $statement = $this ->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, gender, dob, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())");
        $statement->bind_param("ssssss",$name,$email,$gender,$dob,$encryptedPassword,$salt);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $statement->close();

        if ($result) {
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =?");
            $statement->bind_param("s", $email);
            $statement->execute();
            $user = $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $statement->close();
            return $user;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

After reading a lot I know the problem is caused because conn isn't declared anywhere (well it is, but at the top of the class as private $conn;)

There is also a construct in the class

```
 function construct(){
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    $db = new db_connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
```

This simply calls to db_connect & connect()

```
function connect(){
    require_once 'db_config.php';

    $this -> conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    return $this -> conn;
}
```

I have managed data transfer in PHP before, but that was when I made a connection within each class & there wasn't a class specifically for functions.

I have read that declaring $conn as a global is bad practice due to spaghetti coding styles, and I have also seen you can pass the connection in as a variable, however I don't understand how I could do this from **register.php to db_functions** when the construct is within db_functions

If anyone can provide good tutorials/explanations or how I could solve this problem it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor method will not work as a 'magic method' if you don't have `__` before it.

Change;

```
 function construct(){
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    $db = new db_connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
```

to;

```
 function __construct(){
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    $db = new db_connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
```

[Documentation for magic methods can be found here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

[Documentation for constructors can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)